# XJB Pattern annotation invalid character & (ampersand)

Tags: java, regex

I have the following snippet on the xjb:

```
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='MyType']/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='field']">
        <annox:annotate target="field">
            <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.validation.constraints.Pattern" regexp="[A-Za-z0-9&]{1,8}" groups="javax.validation.groups.Default" message="Invalid pattern" />         
        </annox:annotate>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

However, the pattern that I'm trying to use, should allow only letters and numbers and the ampersand (&). However, the ampersand (&) breaks the xjb validation, with the following error:

**The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.**

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Use the entity - `regexp="[A-Za-z0-9&amp;]{1,8}"`.  If it does not work, use `\x26` or `\u0026` instead of `&amp;`.

Comment: Answer it, to choose as the best answer!

Comment: A JAXB bindings file is still just an XML file.  You cannot place a `&` directly in an XML file without escaping it.

Comment: @VGR Inside a CData block, it would not need turning into an entity. Here, it is just part of an attribute value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the XML entity for the ampersand as you are using it inside an attribute value:

```
regexp="[A-Za-z0-9&amp;]{1,8}"
                  ^^^^^
```